# Ionic ionScroll not working with AmCharts

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, amcharts

I'm trying to make basic chart (created using AmChart library) scrollable n axis X with using ionScroll component:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionScroll/

Problem is that, if I'm using to move in ionScroll component on mobile device I get error message:

```
E/Web Console﹕ Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'contains' of undefined:2882
```

I don't know if this problem is caused by amchart or ionic but it does not working on mobile devices (in Chrome with emulation of the mobile device it is working).

I'm using Ionic version:
**v1.0.0-beta.13 "lanthanum-leopard**

What can cause this error?

Here is attached content of the template where is chart div and ion-scroll:

```
<ion-view title="Hourly charts" animation="slide-in-up">

    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon icon  ion-arrow-left-c" ui-sref="home">
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>

  <!--content-->
  <ion-content ng-controller="HourlyChartsCtrl"
               ng-init="setDateRange('today');">
      <div class="chart_range_date">
        Date: {{dateFrom}} 8 AM - 6 PM
      </div>
      <!--daily charts-->
      <ion-scroll
          id="scroll_hourly"
          style="width:100%;"
          class="vh72"
          direction="x"
          has-bouncing="false"
          locking="false"
          paging="true">
      <div id="chartdiv_hourly" class="vh72" style="width:200%;">
      </div>
  </ion-scroll>

  <h3 class="swipeNote">Swipe here to move through weeks</h3>


</ion-content>

<!--tabbar-->
  <div class="tabs-striped tabs-background-positive tabs-light tabs-icon-left">
        <div class="tabs">
            <a class="tab-item active" ui-sref="hourly-chart" href="/#/hourly-chart">
                Hours
            </a>
            <a class="tab-item" ui-sref="daily-chart" href="/#/daily-chart">
                Days
            </a>
            <a class="tab-item " ui-sref="monthly-chart" href="/#/monthly-chart">
                Months
            </a>
        </div>
  </div>

</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't diagnose that error without the JavaScript, but amChart has its own features for managing scrolling http://www.amcharts.com/demos/line-chart-with-scroll-and-zoom/.

I have used highcharts (not amCharts) and found that the chart has touch events that can override the scroll area behavior if the touch events occur on the chart. amChart says it is supported with touch events, so I would expect a similar behavior.

Instead of trying to use ionScroll to handle horizontal navigation, why not use the built in chart's scrolling?

Comment: Hello, I tried chart scrolling in Amcharts before, but is absolutely unusable for touchscreen devices (you can try to run demo in link you provided), so i want to "hack" it using ionScroll which  seems to be acceptable in order of the performance and usability.